# Uncaught SyntaxError in express application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, chart.js

I'm trying to stream live data with websockets to Chartjs  however I keep receiving the following error.

> main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <[image: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token]
>   [image]

What am I doing wrong?

my server code/html looks like this: 
[image]

> server.js

```
const config = require('./config.json');
const express = require('express');
const SocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const path = require('path');
const PORT = config.PORT|| process.env.PORT ;
const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, config.INDEX);


const server = express()
    .use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX))
    .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));



const wss = new SocketServer({ server });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('Client connected');
    ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});
setInterval(() => {
    wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
        client.send(new Date().toTimeString());
    });
}, 1000);
```

> index.html

```
<html>

<body>
    <p>Hello, World</p>
    <p id='server-time'></p>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js" ></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script>
        var HOST = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws')
        var ws = new WebSocket(HOST);
        var el = document.getElementById('server-time');
        ws.onmessage = function(event) {
            el.innerHTML = 'Server time: ' + event.data;
        };


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> main.js

```
console.log("hello,world");

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The file `main.js` in the image looks completely different from the code snippet you posted here. It contains HTML tags, no wonder there is a syntax error.

Comment: The main.js doesn't contain any html, when you travel to the error it takes you to index.html.

Comment: In the image, it very much looks like you have the `main.js` file open, and it begins with `<html>`. When you look at the error message, that makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: I posted a .gif to better illustrate what I'm seeing.

Comment: From what I can see in the GIF, both the `(index)` and the `main.js` file contain HTML code.

Comment: Yes,  index and main.js both contain HTML code but i've included a second gif showing that the actual file contains javascript and the website is showing the index.html for the main.js file

Comment: ...you're both right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have your Express app configured like this:

```
const server = express()
  .use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));
```

that call to `.use()` with no path specified like the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use) recommend?  it means that for every single request received by your app, the file specified by `INDEX` will be emitted.  So when the browser parses `index.html` and sees a `<script>` tag pointing to `main.js`, it asks your app for `/main.js` and gets `INDEX`.  When your browser expects Javascript but gets HTML, it throws the SyntaxError you see in your console.

try using explicit routes and middleware functions (and HTTP request types) in your app:

```
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(INDEX);
});
app.get('/main.js', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('/path/to/main.js');
});
```

(that's a naive example but it should get you started.)

Comment: How would I include node_modules?

Comment: nvm for those who are wondering app.use('/node_modules',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'node_modules')));